# Snapshot Parameter / Services returning NaN in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, nan, angular2-services

I am having trouble passing parameters from one component to the next using a router and activated route in Angular2

My EdmundsAPI Service:

```
  getModels(makeNiceName: string): Observable<Models> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL +
      + makeNiceName + '/models?year=2017&view=basic' + this.apiKey)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

My 'from' component (Makes):

```
  goToModels(makeNiceName: string): void {
    this.router.navigate ( [ '/models', { data: makeNiceName } ] );
  }
```

My 'to' component (Models):
(Variable 'makeNiceName' after 'export class' declaration):

```
 makeNiceName: string = this.route.snapshot.params[ 'data' ];

  getModels(): void {
    this._EdmundsAPIService.getModels(this.makeNiceName)
      .subscribe(
        //Do Stuff here
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

My API URL from Models.getModels() (from Chrome Browser Inspect --> Network):

BaseURL + **/NaN/** models?year=2017&view=basic + apiKey

Why is **NaN** being in place of my 'makeNiceName' variable, which is a string which I would like to pass to my Services to make a URL

Comment: try `this._EdmundsAPIService.getModels(makeNiceName)` insted

Comment: @Jag that's a snippet from an ES6 class, that won't work because `this.` is required.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to ensure `makeNiceName` is the string you expect it to be?

Comment: @Adam, yes, `makeNiceName` is a `string` that returns the parameter of the snapshot, I even replaced `+ makeNiceName +` with `+ 'acura' +` and still got NaN. For some reason, it's checking if it's a number, which isn't necessary

Comment: @Adam, In fact, when I change  the `data=123` from `data=acura` it shows up in the URL, why is it checking if `makeNiceName` is a number - which it isnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `getModels` has two plusses in a row, which seems to insert `NaN` into a string.

Similarly, when I evaluate `'string' + + 'hello'` the result is `"stringNaN"`. But when I try `'string' + + 123` the result is `"string123"`

Try this:

```
getModels(makeNiceName: string): Observable<Models> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseURL +
    makeNiceName + '/models?year=2017&view=basic' + this.apiKey)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: what a silly mistake! ughh! Thanks a million, you saved me hours of debugging other functions.. Haha thanks again @Adam!

Comment: Happens to the best of us!